# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT UITableview

Tags: xcode

The thread 1 : signal SIGABRT error message i'm receiving is.

2014-01-29 08:42:03.158 Ribbit[3982:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "98G-p6-YMF-view-0TQ-oK-A9Q" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:

I'm not understanding why my UITableView is not loading.

Comment: We shouldn't have to be guessing what it is you did.  More information please?  Are you using storyboards, how was the tableview created, etc. I answered below, but it was based on a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you changed the name or deleted a past tableview and then replaced it, but the program is still looking for the old one.  Go into the storyboard file and find the yellow icon with a box in it under the view (the file's owner icon):
[image]

Or on the left side of the screen in the xib file like this:[image]

Right click on it.  Find an outlet with a warning sign next to it, and hit the X to delete it.  This should fix the problem.  Let me know if this works!

Comment: i found that i had a class named wrong in one of the view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If You're dealing with a TableViewController, Make sure the identifier used in the ViewController File 'medthod:
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

is also set on the story board